# How to find a confidence interval for the total number of events

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

I have detector which will detect an event with some probability *p*. If the detector says that an event occured, then that is always the case, so there are not false-positives. After I run it for some time, I get *k* events detected. I would like to calculate what the total number of events that occured was, detected or otherwise, with some confidence, say 95%.

So for example, let's say I get 13 events detected. I would like to be able to calculate that there were between 13 and 19 events with 95% confidence based on *p*.

Here's what I've tried so far:

The probability of detecting *k* events if there were *n* total is:

`binomial(n, k) * p^k * (1 - p)^(n - k)`

The sum of that over *n* from *k* to infinity is:

`1/p`

Which means, that the probability of there being *n* events total is:

`f(n) = binomial(n, k) * p^(k + 1) * (1 - p)^(n - k)`

So if I want to be 95% sure I should find the first partial sum `f(k) + f(k+1) + f(k+2) ... + f(k+m)` which is at least 0.95 and the answer is `[k, k+m]`. Is this the correct approach? Also is there a closed formula for the answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would choose to use the [negative binomial distribution](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture16.pdf), which returns the probability that there will be X failures before the k_th success, when the constant probability of a success is p.

Using an example

```
k=17 # number of successes
p=.6 # constant probability of success
```

the mean and sd for the failures are given by

```
mean.X <- k*(1-p)/p
sd.X <- sqrt(k*(1-p)/p^2)
```

The distribution of the failures X, will have approximately that shape

```
plot(dnbinom(0:(mean.X + 3 * sd.X),k,p),type='l')
```

So, the number of failures will be (with 95% confidence) approximately between

```
qnbinom(.025,k,p)
[1] 4
```

and

```
qnbinom(.975,k,p)
[1] 21
```

So you inerval would be [k+qnbinom(.025,k,p),k+qnbinom(.975,k,p)] (using the example's numbers [21,38] )

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to pick a distribution for $ n, p(n) $ you can apply Bayes law.

You know that the probability of k events occuring given that n have actually occured is governed by a binomial distribution

$$p(k|n) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{(n-k)}$$

The thing you really want to know is the probability of n events having actually occured, given that you observed k. By Bayes lay:

$$p(n|k) = \frac{p(k|n)p(n)}{p(k)}$$

By applying the theorem of total probability, we can write:

$$p(n|k) = \frac{p(k|n)p(n)}{\sum_{n'} p(k|n')p(n')}$$

So without further information, about the distribution of $p(n)$ you can't really go any further.

However, if you want to pick a distribution for $p(n)$ for which there is a value $n$ greater than which $p(n) = 0$, or sufficiently close to zero, then you can do a bit better. For example, assume that the distribution of $n$ is uniform in the range $[0,n_{\max}]$. this case:

$$p(n) = \frac{1}{n_{\max}}$$

The Bayesian formulation simplifies to:

$$p(n|k) = \frac{p(k|n)}{\sum_{n'} p(k|n')}$$

As for the final part of the problem, I agree that the best approach is to perform a cumulative summation over $p(n|k)$, to generate the cumulative probability distribution function, and iterate until the 0.95 limit is reached.

Given that this question migrated from SO, toy sample code in python is attached below

```
import numpy.random

p = 0.8
nmax = 200

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return reduce( lambda a,b : a*b, xrange(1,n+1), 1 )

def ncr(n,r):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n-r))

def binomProbability(n, k, p):
    p1 = ncr(n,k)
    p2 = p**k
    p3 = (1-p)**(n-k)
    return p1*p2*p3

def posterior( n, k, p ):
    def p_k_given_n( n, k ):
        return binomProbability(n, k, p)
    def p_n( n ):
        return 1./nmax
    def p_k( k ):
        return sum( [ p_n(nd)*p_k_given_n(nd,k) for nd in range(k,nmax) ] )
    return (p_k_given_n(n,k) * p_n(n)) / p_k(k)


observed_k   = 80
p_n_given_k  = [ posterior( n, observed_k, p ) for n in range(0,nmax) ]
cp_n_given_k = numpy.cumsum(p_n_given_k)
for n in xrange(0,nmax):
    print n, p_n_given_k[n], cp_n_given_k[n]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you measure $k$ events and know your detection efficiency is $p$ you can automatically correct your measured result up to the "true" count $k_\mathrm{true} = k/p$.

Your question is then about finding the range of $k_\mathrm{true}$ where 95%
of the observations will fall. You can use the [Feldman-Cousins method](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9711021) to estimate this interval. If you have access to [ROOT](https://web.archive.org/web/20100723100814/http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) there is a class to do this calculation for you.

You would calculate the upper and lower limits with Feldman-Cousins from the
*uncorrected* number of events $k$ and then scale them up to 100% with $1/p$.
This way the actual number of measurements determines your uncertainty, not
some scaled number that wasn't measured.

```
{
gSystem->Load("libPhysics");

const double lvl = 0.95;
TFeldmanCousins f(lvl);

const double p = 0.95;
const double k = 13;
const double k_true = k/p;

const double k_bg = 0;

const double upper = f.CalculateUperLimit(k, k_bg) / p;
const double lower = f.GetLowerLimit() / p;

std::cout << "["
  lower <<"..."<<
  k_true <<"..."<<
  upper <<
  "]" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. I think this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of confidence intervals. Confidence intervals allow you to assess where the true value of the parameter is located. So, in your case, you can construct a confidence interval for $p$. It does not make sense to construct an interval for the data.

Having said that, once you have an estimate of $p$ you can calculate the probability that you will observe different realizations such as 14, 15 etc using the binomial pdf.

Comment: Well I already know p. I also know the amount of events detected: k. So the total events is somewhere around k/p. I would like to find out an interval around k/p so I can be say 95% sure that the total number of events is inside it. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to compute an interval for N in binomial sampling, where p is known. It makes sense to try to do that.